# django apache deployement for more than one listinening ports

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to deploy a `Django` website on `apache`. I did this.

**tracking.wsgi**

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append('/home/jarvis/django-tracking/tracking')
sys.path.append('/home/jarvis/django-tracking/tracking/tracking')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tracking.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

and

**/etc/apache2/http.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias daifotis.dyndns.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@daifotis.com

    DocumentRoot /home/jarvis/code/

    Alias /media /home/jarvis/django-tracking/tracking/tracking/static
    Alias /static /home/jarvis/django-tracking/tracking/tracking/static
    #AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /home/jarvis/django-tracking/tracking/tracking/static/$1

    <Directory /home/jarvis/django-tracking/tracking/tracking/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/jarvis/django-tracking/tracking/tracking/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/jarvis/django-tracking/tracking>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>



    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jarvis/tracking.wsgi

    <Directory  /home/jarvis/django-tracking/tracking>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now whenever I type localhost and if the apache is running the site will display. so far so good.

My question are as follows:

1. In Django have a static_root also and we do a `collectstatic`, I still havent used that. What is the use of that over this ?  How can I use that ? 
2. I want to make apache listen to a port say 8888 and keep listening for I will send data at regular intervals on that port. How can I do that ? 
3. While using Django runserver I was able to see what was happening with the help of print statements in the terminal here How can I do that for I want to see who and what kind of data is coming on the port 8888.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. You *are* using static_root: you have correctly set up Apache to serve from /static and /media, that's all you need.
2. That's not a job for Apache. You'll need a standalone script that listens on a socket.
3. Use the logging module to write to Apache's logs.